# circular layout design in Android ui

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I am trying to design ui part in android which hold a logo in the center of the layout.and every image take a certain distance and take position respect radius with making circle and another image take same and some   far than the one..just like solar system pictorial view.i got round view of those images but ,there are no line...plz help me...layout will just like,except multiple image,there just one image in one circle..

[image: http://cdn.ilovefreesoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/Circle-Dock-Layout-1.png/]

Comment: https://github.com/anupcowkur/Android-Wheel-Menu check this if it helps

Comment: Were you able to do it?

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/sababado/CircularView
This may also be of assistance. It allows for a center image and background color. It also allows for the same customization for each of it's surrounding `Markers`.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `CircleLayout`: https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/CircleLayout

Just put it in a `FrameLayout` together with your center image, and you are good to go.

Comment: Put the CircleLayout in a FrameLayout, and add different ImageViews for the background images into the same FrameLayout.